# having a type error while running animation

Tags: python, pygame

This is the code I am using for animation. I use this method every time. For some reason it's giving me a `TypeError` saying that it cannot compare `int` values and a `list`.

This is my code:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800
SCREEN_WIDTH = 500
SCREEN_DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_WIDTH))
for_clock = pygame.time.Clock()
for_count_1 = 0
while True:
    for_clock.tick(30)
    SCREEN_DISPLAY.fill((255, 255, 255))
    class for_game():
        def __init__(self):
            global for_count_1
            
            self.for_game_showcase = []
            self.for_game_showcase.append("game front.png")
            self.for_game_showcase.append("game front.png")
            self.for_game_showcase.append("game front.png")
            self.for_game_showcase.append("game front.png")
            self.for_game_showcase.append("game front.png")
            self.for_game_showcase.append("game front.png")
            self.for_game_showcase.append("game front.png")
            for_count_1 += 1
            
            if for_count_1 >= self.for_game_showcase:
                for_count_1 = 0
                
            self.for_game_name_showcase = self.for_game_showcase[for_count_1]
            self.for_game_name_showcase_scale = 
            pygame.transform.scale(self.for_game_name_showcase, (400, 250))
            
        def for_game_name(self):
            SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(self.for_game_name_showcase_scale, (190, 130))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
            
        for_class_call_1 = for_game()
        for_class_call_1.for_game_name()
            
        pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

ahh!! a common mistake. see you are comparing for_count_1 which is a int to self.for__game_showcase in line if for_count_1 >= self.for_game_showcase it cannot be right as I told for_count_1 is int and self.for_game_showcase is a list as you are appending things to it in line  self.for_game_showcase.append("game front.png") that is you do with list and not int and thus python cannot compare list with it as said in error cannot "compare int values and a list" so that is you get the error.................
one more advice, write your class outside of the while loop and then make object of that class and then you can use that object in the while loop
Welcome : )

Comment: it would be really helpful if you give me a direct solution to fix the issue as i just started on animation yesterday pls

Comment: ok, in direct words, you cant compare a list type which is for_game_showcase to for_count_1 which is a int

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare the list `for_game_showcase` with the integral value `for_count_1` . However you can compare the length (number of items) of the list with an integral value. Get the length of the list with [`len(s)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len):

<s>`if for_count_1 >= self.for_game_showcase:`</s>

```py
if for_count_1 >= len(self.for_game_showcase):
```